# R-squared for user-defined prediction algorithms

Tags: r-squared

I've been working on a machine learning project for a while and I've come up with an algorithm that does what I want it to do (predict some values). I wondered if it is possible to calculate R-squared for my results.

My results are like this (test):

```
Predictions  Observations:
4.25         4.30
4.15         4.25
3.70         3.75
3.25         3.15
...
```

How can I calculate R-squared for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate an R-squared with the above results, you can perform [simple linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) with Predictions as your predictor, x, variable and Observations as your outcome, y, variable using any standard statistical program.

The below R code will allow you to do so:

`slr <- lm(Observations ~ Predictions, data=yourdata)`

`summary(slr)`

Comment: Also, R-squared here is just the square of the Pearson correlation, to be calculated using the appropriate function or command in your favourite software.

Comment: @NickCox, you are very correct as well (thanks for adding that to my answer), Sinead, whichever approach you choose will net you the same R-squared, cheers!